# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am attempting to parse a JSON document and enter its information into a UICollectionView. I had tested the parsing before working on the UICollectionViewDelegate/Flowlayout/DataSource etc. It was returning the correct information, however now I am getting this error. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
class ViewModel {

let urlString = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/nxtapnxtap/clubsinfo.json"

var clubNames = [String]()
var smImg  = [UIImage]()
var lgImg = [String]()

func fetchItems(success: () -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        var jsonError: NSError?
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary // Error here --> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        if let unwrappedError = jsonError {
            println("jsonError: \(unwrappedError)")
        } else {
            self.clubNames = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.name.label") as [String]
            self.smImg = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.smimg.label") as [UIImage]
            self.lgImg = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.lgimg.label") as [String]
            success()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object coming back from JSONObjectWithData is nil. You are trying to force cast it as an NSDictionary. You need to check if it can be cast to an NSDictionary before you act on it:

```
func fetchItems(success: () -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        var jsonError: NSError?
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {
            self.clubNames = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.name.label") as [String]
            self.smImg = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.smimg.label") as [UIImage]
            self.lgImg = json.valueForKeyPath("entry.lgimg.label") as [String]
            success()
        } else if let unwrappedError = jsonError {
            println("jsonError: \(unwrappedError)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help bjtitus - this did remove the previous error and now I am getting a (No value) error meaning that the data being returned is nil. What I'm not understanding is why the data is coming back nil. Is it that the json.valueForKeyPath is wrongly written? I am confused as this snippet worked before (I was able to print out the data that was returned). Is there a possibility that something else in my code is interfering with this snippet?

Comment: Here is an example of the json document: { "entry":[
           {
           "name":{
           "label":"Samplename"
           },

Comment: If that is the full json document, it certainly isn't valid. Check the json with a validator: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: No this isn't the full document, I just wanted to show the 'name' path. It's funny I checked the full document on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ prior to upload on AS3 and it was correct. Maybe it is somehow changed during upload. Thanks again for your help.